# Passing route parameters in .Net Core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, mvvm, razor-pages

I want to pass parameters to `OnGet()` method but it's not stable and everytime is different, For example:

```
test.com/book
test.com/book/page/word
test.com/book/page
test.com/book/page/word/...
```

the parameters are not stable and are created dynamically.

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle this with the [`@page` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes).

There are several options based on your actual needs.

**You know the structure of your URL in advance**

In your `.cshtml` page, you add the `@page` directive, with each optional parameter followed by a question mark. Note that you can also specify [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraint-reference) to specify that a particular parameter needs to be a certain type like an integer (e.g. here `line` is an optional integer).

```
@page "/book/{pageName?}/{line:int?}/{word?}"
```

In your model class, you add nullable optional parameters matching the names in the `@page` directive:

```cs
public void OnGet([FromRoute] string pageName= null, [FromRoute] int? line = null, [FromRoute] string word = null)
{
    // TODO handle parameters
    // note that line is guaranteed to be an integer
}
```

**You don't know the exact structure of your URL**

In that case, you can use a wildcard parameter, specified with a star before the parameter name:

```
@page "/book/{*content}"
```

```cs
public void OnGet([FromRoute] string content= null)
{
    // TODO handle content
}
```

In that case, `content` will contain the entire string passed after `/book/`, forward slashes included, such as `page/word/5/test`. You can then process it depending on your needs.

Comment: You need to be careful with multiple optional parameters: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/339/optional-parameters-in-razor-pages-routing